# javascript delete all occurrences of a char in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to delete all characters like `[` or `]` or `&` in a string i.E. :
"[foo] & bar" -> "foo bar"

I don't want to call replace 3 times, is there an easier way than just coding:

`var s="[foo] & bar";`

`s=s.replace('[','');`

`s=s.replace(']','');`

`s=s.replace('&','');`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[Regular expressions *<sup>[xkcd]</sup>*](http://xkcd.com/208/) (I feel like him ;)):

```
s = s.replace(/[\[\]&]+/g, '');
```

Reference:

- [MDN - `string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [MDN - Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/

**Side note**:

JavaScript's `replace` function only replaces the *first occurrence* of a character. So even your code would not have replaced all the characters, only the first one of each. If you want to replace *all occurrences*, you have to use a *regular expression* with the *`g`lobal modifier*.

Comment: thank you very much! btw: the xkcd comic is very funny :) is there the possibility to even delete the 'bar' in '[foo] & bar' i think that wouldnt be /[/[/]&(bar)]+/g

Comment: to my question with deleting 'bar' : the regex would be `/[\[\]&]+|bar/g`

Comment: MDN documentation, concise example, explanation, XKCD reference... this answer is thoroughly underappreciated!

Answer (score 17):

Today, in 2021 you can use the `replaceAll` function:

```
let str = "Hello. My name is John."

let newStr = str.replaceAll('.', '')

console.log(newStr) // result -> Hello My name is John

let nextStr = str.replaceAll('.', '&')

console.log(nextStr) // result -> Hello& My name is John&
```

Comment: Can you provide node version and emac verison for this

Comment: You need to use Nodejs v15. This relies on the V8 engine version 8.6 which includes replaceAll